# Py2App - ImportError: dlopen

Tags: python, import, fpdf, py2app

I'm trying to convert a python file by Py2app to a Mac OS app.

In this file I'm using fpdf2 to write in different pdf's, but looks like I have some problems with this package and the use of py2app.

Thats why I tested it with a really small where I just use fpdf2 program:

```
test = "test"
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('times', size=20)
pdf.cell(0, 12, txt="Test", ln=True, align='L')
pdf.output('test.pdf')
```

With this setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['test for compile.py']
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

And there I get the same Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-/test_for_compile/dist/test for compile.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 463, in <module>
    _run()
  File "-/test_for_compile/dist/test for compile.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 457, in _run
    exec(compile(source, script, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "-/test_for_compile/test for compile.py", line 2, in <module>
    from fpdf import FPDF
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fpdf/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .fpdf import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 37, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 89, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_jpeg_resync_to_restart'
2022-02-21 14:53:48.261 test for compile[6126:387824] Launch error
2022-02-21 14:53:48.261 test for compile[6126:387824] Launch error
See the py2app website for debugging launch issues
```

On https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugging.html they write following to import problems:

> Some common problems are:
>
> An import statement fails due to a missing module or package
>
> This generally happens when the dependency cannot be found by the source code analyzer, > either due to dynamic imports (using **import**() or importlib to load a module), or
> due to imports in a C extension.

And here more detailed
https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html

But to be honest I don't get if they mean now my problem, and what I can do to solve it.

So I would be really happy for some help :)

Comment: Might be worth posting as an issue on [Github](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues?q=is%3Aissue).

Answer (score 0):

The error `ImportError: dlopen` often means you have a mistake in your setup.py file. In your case, you imported the packages "fpdf" and "FPDF" but did not include them in your app build.

**Here is what your setup.py should look like:**

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['test.py']
DATA_FILES = ['fpdf','FPDF']
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': False,
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files = DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

If you right-click the test.app file in your "dist" folder and click "show package contents", you will see that the test.pdf file will be in Contents > Resources > test.pdf.